# SQLite option missing from Data Explorer

Tags: delphi, sqlite, dbexpress, delphi-xe3

I am creating an application with *Delphi XE3 (Ultimate Edition)* that will utilise an embedded SQLite database. I watched various videos in relation to it and I noticed that my Data Explorer did not match that of the video. At first my Data Explorer was empty, all that was there was `dbExpress`. I've also tried re-running the installer several times and `DataSnap`, `DBXPool`, `DBXTrace`, `IBToGo` and `InterBas` appeared, but it was not because of the installation re-run. Anyway, what can I do to get the SQLite option to appear for me?

This is currently what my Data Explorer looks like:

[image: Data Explorer]

Comment: Which edition are you using, Starter? See [Feature Matrix](http://www.embarcadero.com/products/delphi/delphi-feature-matrix) (pdf).

Comment: I am using the Ultimate Edition.

Comment: +1. That was quick. :-) I added the SQLite tag, which I should have suggested before as well.

Comment: Oh I forgot about that one, thank you Ken! And I'm quite desperate to get this database application up and running.

Comment: Look at dbxdrivers.ini and dbxconnections.ini. Are there any entries for Sqlite?

Comment: @Ertunç - dbxconnections is empty. dbxdrivers on the other hand contains DBXTrace and DBXPool. I've added SQLite to that list and it now appears in the Data Explorer! I'm just unsure if it is actually going to work though. Thank you!

Comment: You need to place connection vendor library dll files correctly. Maybe you may have to change the PATH variable in Windows environment options. I remember myself tackling with these in some previous Delphi version to set it work correctly with mysql.

Comment: Actually all I had to do was add SQLite to the list, but thank you! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check dbxdrivers.ini and dbxconnections.ini for dbexpress configuration. You may need to add an entry for Sqlite dbexpress configuration.